# Добавление кнопок при первом заходе в телеграмм бота

Tags: telegram-bot

Можно ли добавлять кнопки в приветственное сообщение бота?

[image]

Например, заменить заготовку "/start" на кнопку [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать своеобразное меню, введя **@BotFather**-у команду `/setcommands`. Далее выберите команды в меню и их описание. Их нужно вводить сообщением:

```
команда1 - описание
команда2 - ещё описание
```

Меню будет выглядеть примерно так:

[image: Скриншот меню]

Comment: Да, я знаю про это.  Меня интересует можно ли добавить именно кнопки под приветственным описанием?

Comment: @nubik нет, такого, скорее всего, нельзя

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя, если речь идет о новом пользователе, который просматривает описание канала. Кнопки прорисовываются вместе с сообщением, отправляемым пользователю. Тебе как минимум надо знать ID пользователя, чтобы отправить ему сообщение